# How do I remove redundant iOS simulator entries from Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

How do I remove all these extra simulators from my Xcode menu?

[image: Redundant iOS simulators in Xcode]

Comment: Maybe this? /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**XCode** > **Window** > **Devices** :

> Then use the delete key or click the gear icon to remove simulators.

Comment: Thanks. Know of any way to delete more than one at once?

Comment: Unfortunately I think it's one at a time for whatever reason... There is a directory `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/` which is where I believe the devices/simulators are stored, although if you mess around with things in there proceed with caution.

Comment: It takes over 30 seconds to delete a simulator with over 100 simulators this would take almost an hour. :(

Comment: @AndrewPaulSimmons: If it takes you over 30 seconds to remove a simulator then you've got issues far beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: 30 Seconds?
Backspace + Enter = Sim Gone! Next. like 2 seconds maybe

Answer (score 31):

If you want to do this quickly I'd recommend fastlane tools
you can reset simulators with one line

```
fastlane snapshot reset_simulators
```

install fastlane tools

```
sudo gem install fastlane
```

Make sure, you have the latest version of the Xcode command line tools installed:

```
xcode-select --install
```

(https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/capture_ios_screenshots#completely-reset-all-simulators)

And the command is

```
fastlane snapshot reset_simulators
```

Comment: With 500 simulators to remove, you saved me 20 mind-numbing minutes.

Comment: You are golden. I was missing 10.3 simulators and was not able to add them. This fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to delete the Simulators you don't want to see on the run destinations drop-down menu. On Xcode 9 you can just hide the ones that you don't need.

1. Go to **Window > Devices and Simulators** (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>)
2. Pick the Simulator from the left and untick 'Show as run destination' as seen below:

[image: Untick 'Show as run destination']

Comment: This does not work :( 

"Show as run destination" is checked on every device, but I only see one device per OS.

Comment: Never mind my target deployment was set to a newer version, so it did not work on lower simulator versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove devices easily now in XCode 9, but use the Simulator toolbar.
With a Simulator running, go to the top bar and go to 
Hardware -> Device -> Manage Devices then select Simulators. You are presented with the option [Devices | Simulators] So select simulators.
Then work your way down the list, and untick the Simulators, and OS versions you don't want. Too easy. When you look in XCode for a Simulator to use, the list will now be much shorter.
 [Removing unwanted Simulators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMenf.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice shell script that deletes all simulators and creates a list of new ones for you on GitHub without the need of Fastlane (even though Fastlane is worth to have anyway):

https://github.com/jerolimov/reset_simulators

Comment: doesn't it remove only "created" simulators (i.e. which you ran before), but not the whole list of available sims?

Comment: for me it deleted all, but it is some years ago, maybe this changed

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, in more recent versions of Xcode (e.g., Version 13.4.1) it is easy to delete multiple simulators at once.

In Xcode go to Windows -> Device and Simulators, the choose the Simulators tab. A list of devices will appear, from which you can multi-select and then delete.

[image: Screenshot showing simulators in Apple Xcode]

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to delete all existing simulators you can simply use `xcrun simctl delete all`