# Where can I download the iOS 10 simulator runtime file?

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode8, ios10

I want to test my apps in the iOS 10 simulator, but I'm not sure where to get the `.runtime` file for iOS 10. I don't see a download for it under Components in Xcode 8. Where can I download the `.runtime` file for iOS 10 (if it exists)?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: I forgot to mention: As I was trying to fix another problem (before I asked this question), I ended up deleting all of my runtimes and redownloading them (except for iOS 10).**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this has been open for long enough and Xcode 8/iOS 10 are out of beta, plus I solved this problem a week after this was asked, so I'll post my own answer. I ended up redownloading and reinstalling the entire Xcode 8 beta which includes the `.runtime` file in itself. Bit of an overkill, but I didn't have any other options at the time.

Answer (score 35):

I ran into this issue earlier today. After installing Xcode - beta, my simulator was still only displaying iOS simulators 9.3 and below. What eventually ended up working for me was:

- Killing the currently running simulator with cmd-Q
- Control clicking (right click) on the Xcode - beta icon in my dock
- Hovering over "Open Developer Tool"
- Selecting Simulator from this menu

Once the simulator launched, I began to see iOS 10 in the Hardware -> Device drop down. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. If it wasn't for Stack Overflow, we'd really get nothing done on iOS. We certainly can't rely on Apple for useful, timely advice on how to get their software to work.

Comment: Who do you think the top responders are to Apple related questions on SO, in the dev forums, on reddit, etc?  I'll give you a hint ... many of them work at a company in Cupertino named after a fruit.

Comment: Aaron, it sounds to me like you were previously running Simulator.app from Xcode 7.3, which is why you didn't see the iOS 10 Simulator.  Once you ran Simulator.app from Xcode 8, you were able to interact with the iOS 10 Simulator.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia - rhymns with grapple

Comment: Also note that you can't set up an iPad 2 simulator with iOS 10.  You have to use the ginormous retina/air simulators if you want to test iOS 10 on a tablet.

Answer (score 15):

Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Simulator

[image: Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Simulator]

close And re-open Xcode again

[image]

Comment: This worked for me after opening and using Xcode 9 Beta 5. None of my simulators were present in Xcode 8.3.3. Adding simulators manually to Xcode 8.3.3 did not work.

Answer (score 12):

All ios 10 simulator are already downloaded with xcode8 - beta it self. You can download additional simulators from preference -> Components.
[image]

And
You can get data for you app in those simulators at following path.

```
/Users/User_ACC_Name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator
```

Comment: I don't see any runtimes in `/Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator`. I do have the 9.3 runtime in `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes`.

Comment: This will not work (at least as of today Xcode 8 - 8S12SD).

Comment: No, as the OP says, the iOS 10 simulator does not appear in the Components list by default. See other Answers for the correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

Ensure existing simulators are closed. Then **open XCode 8 (beta)**:

**Go to menu XCode -> Open Developer Tools -> Simulator.**

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

1. Go to App Store and Make Xcode Update 8.0
2. Open Xcode and it installs the components
3. Go to Menu "Window" > "Devices"
4. Add A New Device (Important one that supports iOS 10))
5. At the end the devices list is updated, and you can run the devices that can run iOS 10 in the simulator

[Steps 1 to 5 Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4h0Y.png)

Answer (score 2):

The iOS 10 Beta Simulator is shipped inside of Xcode 8.0 Beta.  You do not need to download anything extra.  The primary reason for the large size of the Xcode download is for the three simulator runtimes that it contains.

Comment: You missed the OP's comments about not seeing the simulator appear in the Components list. Other Answers (regarding launching via Open Developer Tool) are correct.

Comment: No, I did see that comment.  The reason it doesn't appear in the components list is because it is shipped as part of Xcode 8.  Only the DLC runtimes are listed in that components list.  iOS 10 is not DLC.  It is included in Xcode 8.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing already mentioned worked for me. I was missing iOS 10.3 simulators in Xcode 8.3.3. What worked for me was to reset the simulators using fastlane snapshot tool:

```
sudo gem install snapshot
snapshot reset_simulators
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37814682/1318739