# Xcode 8 not including iOS 10

Tags: ios10, xcode8

I just upgraded to Xcode 8 through App Store, but I cannot find the iOS 10 simulator anywhere.
When I startup the Simulator, it is running iOS 8.4, and if I select "Download Simulators" I only get options of up to iOS 9.3.
Having read other threads it seems like iOS 10 is supposed to be pre selected, but it is not for me. 
I even deleted Xcode and reinstalled from App store, but still no iOS 10. 

I have looked at the similar thread [Where can I download the iOS 10 simulator runtime file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959438/where-can-i-download-the-ios-10-simulator-runtime-file), but that seems to be problems with the beta-version of Xcode, and doesn't work for me.

Screenshots:

[image: Simulators]

[image: Download Simulators]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot what you see in your simulator list in Xcode?

Comment: Edited with screenshots

Comment: Maybe your older Xcode 7 still in Apps folder. The check could be done in terminal too: $ xcode-select -p

Comment: xcode-select points to the correct version (8.0). Also inside of the Xcode package, there is an iOS 10 SDK:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you have to install simulators for iOS 9.3 and other versions upon upgrading? I was surprised to see no simulators loaded as I had seen in previous Xcode versions.

Comment: @Vivek, I haven't installed any simulators. Only 8.4 is visible by default.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @jannej, no solution yet, I'm debugging on my device instead right now.

Comment: sigh...same for me. Xcode8 has been nothing but trouble for me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a last desperate attempt to solve this, I did a complete re-install of Xcode8. It solved mine issues. Before installing Xcode8 I deleted:

1. `/Applications/Xcode.app`
2. `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist`
3. `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist`
4. `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode`
5. `~/Library/Application\ Support/Xcode`
6. `~/Library/Developer/`

And it worked!

[image]

The answer described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959438/where-can-i-download-the-ios-10-simulator-runtime-file) did not work for me.