# There is no IOS 10 Simulator in Xcode 8

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I just upgraded to Xcode 8 but I found out that there is no iOS 10 Simulator. Does anybody know why it is like that?

[image: Screenshot of all listed Simulators]

And now I also added 9.3 simulators but that's it.

Comment: Are you sure that you have Xcode 8? How do you know that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I download the iOS 10 simulator runtime file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959438/where-can-i-download-the-ios-10-simulator-runtime-file)

Comment: @Andrej yes I am sure, because I updated it in AppStore and it says under "Updated in the last 30 days" xCode version 8

Comment: Check to see if you truly have Xcode 8 by going under the Xcode menu and clicking About.

Comment: @TDM Version 8.0 (8A218a)

Comment: Could you try reinstalling Xcode?

Comment: @TDM already did that twice

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the iOS 10 on below path:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/
```

check Inside this folder, there is iOS 10 developer disk image is there or not?

If it is not there you need to download it.After download it add it over there.
And you can view it in xcode. The path will like this after download and put it into xcode.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.0/developerdiskimage.dmg
```

I hope the answer will helpful to you.

Comment: There is a folder called "10.0 (14A345)"

Comment: This might be helpful to you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959438/where-can-i-download-the-ios-10-simulator-runtime-file

or

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50084

Answer (score 0):

While verifying what's going on I've launched Xcode 8 and created a new project and I've seen all simulators. Then closed Xcode.

Next I've launched Xcode 7, created a new project and of course, all simulators for Xcode 7 were normally visible. Then I closed Xcode 7.

Next I've opened the first project (with Xcode 8) and found no simulators at all. So it clearly looks like a bug. (it's not so critical to me so I didn't bother file a Radar)

Solution / workaround: close Xcode and reopen again. Eventually make new project to see all simulators and after few repetitions I'm able again to see all simulators for Xcode 8 in my original project.

Answer (score -3):

xCode->Preferences->Components

Comment: IOS 10 isn't there

Comment: This answer is useful when installing previous ios-simulators. So in xcode 8 for ios 9 and earlier.